# How to call php function when select option changes? Is my designed flawed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple web chat between users and admins. My idea was to create a php object ChatRoom. Users will have a ChatRoom object, instantiated with their user id, which will load up their previous chats (stored in files on the server).
However, I want admins to be able to switch from one chat to another, using the ChatRoom object.

So I created a ChatRoom object, that has a 'load' function, that will go get the users file via an AJAX call to load previous chat, and start a timer interval, to refresh the ChatRoom object every x seconds.
This part is working.

Now I started the admin part, and this is where things get tricky.
Admins have a list of chats (one for each user) in a 'select' tag, and one instance of the ChatRoom created.
Each option of the 'select' has a value corresponding to the user in question.

Now, I want that when I click on a user in the 'select', it calls the 'load' function of my ChatRoom object, and passes the value of the selected user to the load function, to load the logs of the chat with that specific user.

My problem is: how could I detect the change of 'select', get the newly selected value, and call the 'load' function of my ChatRoom object?

My admin page looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <?php
  // initialize
  if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

  $_SESSION['author'] = 'admin';

  // mysql connection
  require_once('db_connection.php');
  $db_object = new dbConnection;
  $db = $db_object->connect();
  ?>

  <select id="chatlist" name="chatlist" size=20 style="width:15em; display:inline-block;">
  <?php
    // prepare select statement
    $sql = "SELECT userid,chatid FROM chats";

    // bind variables to prepared statement as parameters
    if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){

       /* execute statement */
       $stmt->execute();

       /* bind results */
       $stmt->bind_result($userid, $chatid);

       /* fetch values */
       while($stmt->fetch()){
             echo '<option value="'.$chatid.'">'.$userid.'</option>';
       }

      /* close statement */
      $stmt->close();
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <div id="chatcontent" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 1em; vertical-align:top;">
    <?php

      require_once('classes/ChatRoom.php');
      $chat = new ChatRoom;
      $chat->load(????????); // Here I want to pass the value of the selected option
     ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the code, I make a lookup in mysql between the userid and a chatid, but it's not important here.

Here, the load function is working, I tested it. All I need to know, is how to pass it the right parameter.

I'm not sure how to do that. Is my design flawed?

Thank you.

Edit: Here is the content of the load function

```
class ChatRoom{

...

  function load($userid){
    $this->setUserId($userid);
    $this->loadHtml();
  }

  function loadHtml(){
    echo '<div id="chatContainer" style="flex-direction: column">';
    echo '  <div id="chat" style="width:100%">';
    if (isset($this->chatid)){
      $this->filename = "logs/".$this->chatid.".html";
      if(file_exists($this->filename) && filesize($this->filename) > 0){
        $contents = file_get_contents($this->filename);
        echo $contents;
      }
    }
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '  <div id="inputContainer" style="flex-direction: row">';
    echo '    <input id="message-box" style="width:80%"><button id="send-button" style="width:10%">Send</button>';
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">setInterval(loadLog, 2500,"'.$this->filename.'");</script>';
  }
}
```

Where loadLog is:

```
function loadLog(page) {
  var oldscrollHeight = $("#chat")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height before the request

  $.ajax({
    url: page,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
      $("#chat").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div

      //Auto-scroll
      var newscrollHeight = $("#chat")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height after the request
      if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
        $("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: *"how could I detect the change of 'select',"* - hmm, didnt html element has [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event which fires whenever input value changed? you can then use ajax to submit the `select` element value as parameter somewhere or just post with while reloading the page..

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to reload the whole page everytime it changes.

Comment: Based on your current code, there's no reference to the `page` being sent from the `loadLog` function for admins except on the initial page load which calls `ChatRoom::loadHtml()`. You'd need to create a *separate PHP script* to handle the user selection of the desired `chatid` using the `$('#chatlist').on('change')` event with another `$.ajax` call to the new `chatid` handler script.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. What would this new ajax call return then ? I understand that I could detect the change with .on('change'), but even if I make another ajax call, how would I pass the chatid to the already existing ChatRoom object (through the load function).

Comment: You cannot pass anything to the existing `ChatRoom` PHP object, as once it is processed server-side and the response has been sent to the client, it is no longer accessible via Javascript. Hence the need for a separate AJAX request to a separate PHP script to handle the selected `chatid`, which would replace the existing `#chatcontent` DOM element via `$("#chatcontent").html(chatIdAjaxResponseHTML);`, because `setInterval(loadLog, 2500,"'.$this->filename.'");` from the original request in the existing `#chatcontent` DOM element would no longer be valid.

Comment: Ok. So my design is indeed flawed. Once the ChatRoom object has been created, I wouldn't be able to update the `$this->filename` inside, so the `loadLog` function won't load the proper page, because part of this is executed client side, while the php part is executed server side.

Answer (score 0):

inner body and after your content...

```
<script>
let sel = document.getElementById('chatlist');
sel.addEventListener ("change", function () {
   // your ajaxcall goes here
   let selection = this.value; // selection contains the selected user id

});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how would I set call the chatroom load function from there ?

Comment: friend, load the chat content with Ajax, so you need an php file they give you the chat messages, i cant create the file for you. that is your turn.

Comment: The chat content is already loaded via an Ajax call in the ChatRoom object. But I need to tell the ChatRoom object which file to load (via the load function). I added the load function if you want to check it.

Comment: I added a new post with a possible way

Answer (score 0):

This is a way, your chat class ...

```
class ChatRoom{

...

  function load($userid){
    $this->setUserId($userid);
    $this->loadHtml();
  }

  function loadHtml(){
    echo '<div id="chatContainer" style="flex-direction: column">';
    echo '  <div id="chat" style="width:100%">';
    if (isset($this->chatid)){
      $this->filename = "logs/".$this->chatid.".html";
      if(file_exists($this->filename) && filesize($this->filename) > 0){
        $contents = file_get_contents($this->filename);
        echo $contents;
      }
    }
    echo '  </div>';
    echo '  <div id="inputContainer" style="flex-direction: row">';
    // Add a hidden field for the id
    echo '    <input id="chat" type="hidden" value="logs/'.$this->chatid.'.html">';
    echo '    <input id="message-box" style="width:80%"><button id="send-button" style="width:10%">Send</button>';

    echo '  </div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">setInterval(loadLog, 2500, document.querySelector("#chat").value);</script>';
  }
}
```

and my Code ...

```
<script>
let sel = document.getElementById('chatlist');
sel.addEventListener ("change", function () {
   // your ajaxcall goes here
   let selection = this.value; // selection contains the selected user id
   // update the value of the hidden inputfield with the selection
   document.querySelector("#chat").value = "logs/"+selection+".html";
});
</script>
```